# include could not fined load file: CGAL_TBB_support

Tags: cgal, triangulation, tbb

I'm trying to run "Triangulation_3" examples and while doing the "cmake" I get this error:

***CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (include):
include could not find load file:
CGAL_TBB_support***

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and I've already installed TBB library using

***sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev***

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the cmake script of the example from the same release of CGAL you are trying to compile it?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm trying to compile all examples at the same time  by doing the "cmake-gui .." and then the "make", but in the "cmake-gui . ." I get the error written above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the system `libcgal-dev` version 5.0.3, as provided by apt for Ubuntu 20.04. That version of CGAL does not have the CMake module `CGAL_TBB_support.cmake`.

Probably you are using CGAL examples from more recent version of CGAL, maybe one you downloaded or cloned using Git.

If you recent version of CGAL is, for example, at the path `/home/me/downloads/CGAL-5.3`, then set the CMake cache variable `CGAL_DIR` to that directory. You can pass the option `-DCGAL_DIR=/home/me/downloads/CGAL-5.3` to the `cmake` command line, for example. Or set the variable `CGAL_DIR` to `/home/me/downloads/CGAL-5.3` in CMake-GUI. Of course, adjust you the real path on your system.

Comment: Whats is exactly the CMake cache variable CGAL_DIR and how can I find it?

Comment: I've written in the terminal "cmake -DCGAL_DIR=$CMAKE_INSTALLED_PREFIX/lib/CGAL -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .    # configure the examples
make" in the path where I have Triangulation_3 examples and I get exactly the same error "NOTICE: a few examples require TBB and will not be compiled.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!"

Comment: Now I've done the "cmake-gui" and change CGAL_DIR directory to /home/elena/Descargas/Practicas2/cgal, but a lot more errors appear, I don't know if I'm going to have enough characters to paste it: CMake Warning at /home/elena/Descargas/Practicas2/cgal/Installation/cmake/modules/CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram.cmake:49 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target sequential_parallel
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

Comment: Your first error was `include could not find load file: CGAL_TBB_support` and now it is `NOTICE: a few examples require TBB and will not be compiled.`! That is a very different error, even if they are both about TBB. Install the Ubuntu package `libbtbb-dev`.

Comment: I had already install the package and still have the same error

Comment: @ElenaFernández That is quite difficult to help you that way. Maybe you could paste your whole CMake log and also the content of `CMakeCache.txt` to https://gist.github.com/ (and then poste here the URL).

Comment: I've posted here the files I'm trying to compile and the CMakecache.text and everything I have in the folder. The URL is https://github.com/elenaferga/delaunaytriangulation